# Create dynamic view of list item by clicking on tile

Tags: javascript, csom, html, query, promoted-links

I have a "promoted links" list to display some tiles on a page. What I am trying to do now is to display a popup window or a seperate browser window when I click on that tile, based on the list information of the list item. The tile only displays the name of the list item, the popup window is supposed to show more information like the description and more. I know a little bit about Javascript and I think displaying the window itself should be no issue, but how would I go about opening the window by clicking on the tile and passing a parameter like the ID of the list item  to query more information about it?